# do/while loop lazy caterer's sequence

Tags: java, do-while

I can't fully understand [this](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs180/Fall2008Web/projects/p3/). I am currently studying how this one can be done and also, I want the 1st 11 results to be printed (1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46, 56).

Kindly explain and help me do it?

**Note:** I'm using `do`/`while` loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

    public class DoWhileLoop {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N;
        System.out.print("Enter a number ");
        N = in.nextInt();

        int cut0 = 1;
        int totalpieces = 1;
        int Ncut = cutN+((cutN-1)+N); // help me here pls

        do {
        totalpieces = totalpieces + N; // not sure how to construct this too
        totalpieces++;
        }
        while(totalpieces<=56);

        System.out.println(totalpieces + " "); // I would want the 1st 11  outcome to be printed (1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46, 56)
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesnt compile. What are you trying to do, and why isnt it working? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: what the heck is cutN?  It isn't defined within the class but it is called.

Comment: I assumed it was an int, is cut0 supposed to be cutN?

Comment: @jgabb I am trying to solve lazy caterer's sequence here http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs180/Fall2008Web/projects/p3/... that is the Nth cut hehe

Comment: @BenKnoble I want to write this program using do while. A user will input a number and the program should print the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
    String result = "";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number ");
    int numberOfCuts = in.nextInt();

    int pieces = 1;
    int cutCount = 1;

    do {
        result += " " + pieces;

        pieces += cutCount;
        cutCount++;
    }
    while (cutCount <= numberOfCuts);

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: wow, thank you @pmartin8 it really works...but how about it there is a user and he inputs any number of his choice?

Comment: I updated the answer so you have everything. Make sur you accept my aswere if you like it :)

Comment: wow, you are awesome.. how I wish you are my teacher... coz my lecture teacher is a total dick..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int N, cut;
 System.out.print("Enter a number ");
 N = in.nextInt();
    do
    {
        cut = 1+(N*(N+1))/2;
        N--;
    }while(N == 0);

 System.out.println("Total cut: " + cut);
```

Input N = 5 expected output: 16 it's print:

> Enter a number 5
>
> 16